# Laravel calling model after declaring function with colon

Tags: php, laravel

I was reading a short tutorial on Laravel [here](https://murze.be/2016/10/sending-welcome-mail-laravel-5-3/). Since I am not experienced in laravel or development in general I am wondering what this part of the code does exactly:

```
public function approve(): User
```

As it is seems to me, it is the same thing as just calling the model from inside the function like so:

```
App\User::
```

What is the difference in this two approches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're not the same. The first code is utilizing PHP 7's [return type declerations](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration).

It says that the method **must** return an instance of `User` class, or PHP will throw a `TypeError` for you. You can also specify the FQN of the class when defining return type declarations:

```
public function approve(): \App\User
```

It's specially useful when defining interfaces:

```
interface CommentsIterator extends Iterator {
    function current(): Comment; 
    // This enforces that any implementation of current() 
    // method, must return an instance of Comment class.
}
```

See what other RFCs made their way into PHP 7:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

And treat yourself with Jeffrey's screencasts on PHP 7 new features:
https://laracasts.com/series/php7-up-and-running/episodes/3

But the second code (`App\User::whatever()`) is just calling the static method `whatever()` of the `App\User` class. It has nothing to do with the first code example which enforces return types.

Answer (score 4):

The first example you shared:

```
public function approve(): User
```

is simply a feature of PHP7 which allows you to use static type programming practices with PHP. Essentially this new function signature is telling you that this function needs to return a `User` type or it will throw a `TypeError` exception.

The second example you shared:

```
App\User::
```

is using what is called the **Scope Resolution Operator**(`::`) This operator allows you to call Class Level / Static Methods. In Laravel for example, that would be something like:

```
App\User::Find(1);
```

or

```
App\User::Where('id', 1);
```

and these differ from object level methods which would be called like so:

```
$user = new App\User();
$user->id = 1;
$user->save()
```

Notice the class instance uses the `->` operator.

You can learn more about what I mentioned at the following links:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent

Best of luck!